# I can redis-om .equals to work, but not .matches

Tags: node-redis

I've been trying to figure this out, and I have an entry (among 23K) on redis Enterprise that looks like

{ id:"2" elementName:"Garlic" elementType:"powder" elementCarbonFactor:"0.74941" carbonFactorSource:"Agribalyse" unit:"kg" geography:"FRA" }

And if I do the search below, it works perfectly:

```
    console.time("Redis Search time");
    await repository.createIndex().catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error creating index");
      console.log(err);
    });
    let response =await repository.search()
      .where('elementName') // search for the field
      .equals("Garlic") // search for the value
      .return.all(); // return all the results
    console.log(response[0].elementName);
```

However, if I change the above to match entires containing Garlic instead, using **.matches** I get "Process finished with exit code 1" but no error message anywhere as far as I can see

```
          .where('elementName') // search for the field
          .matches("Garlic") // search for the value
          .return.all(); // return all the results
        console.log(response[0].elementName)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Anyone used matches, and have a clue what the issue may be (including me)

Answer (score 0):

I can take no credit for this response.
The trick is, change the schema to use text instead of string, then you chan use matches, which looks for occurrences rather than exact matches (apparently equials is for string, number and boolean, matches is for text)